# How do I fix this mysterious Heroku error that has no specific error that I can identify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Forgive me if this is a duplicate of another post, but I can't seem to identify anything in this error log that I recognize as fixable.  Generally, the topmost error is something in my rails app, and something that I can address.  In this case, I havent a clue.

```
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/tasks.json" for 24.131.239.67 at 2012-06-03 20:53:58 -0700
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:451:in `_run__3347105819948830800__process_action__6324466216974895__callbacks'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/plugins/rpm/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/plugins/rpm/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:255:in `block in perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/plugins/rpm/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/plugins/rpm/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:250:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/plugins/rpm/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:33:in `process_action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/plugins/rpm/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `block in call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/airbrake-3.1.0/lib/airbrake/rack.rb:30:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/airbrake-3.1.0/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:15:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `block in call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:77:in `call'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `block in pre_process'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-06-04T03:53:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 166ms (Views: 16.4ms | ActiveRecord: 71.9ms)
```

Comment: Note that this occurs when I hit a json endpoint, ex: /tasks.json which returns a list of tasks in an action #index that has a reasonable-sized body of code but doesnt do anything too crazy.

Comment: Also note that the request succeeds, the json output is displayed and no one is the wiser, save for the several hundred lines of error in my log.

Comment: It could just be something out there logging the stack trace and not a real error. Are you sure there isn't anywhere in your code a call to "caller" and printing it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a new-relic related error. Have you followed herokus' [installation instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic)?